# Default login URL in Tridion?

Tags: core-service, cme

We have SSO authorization and logging in via SSO to Tridion CMS, but are there other ways used to login to Tridion?
Is there a default custom loginpage available in Tridion, if yes would you be kind to share that url with me?

Thanks,
bvl

Answer (score 8):

Tridion does not handle authentication itself, so there is no login page, no passwords stored in the database etc.

Tridion accepts pre-authenticated users passed to it from other authentication mechanisms. "Out of the box" this is done via Windows authentication against the IIS server that is running the Content Manager website. It can also be via an LDAP directory or an alternative SSO system.

In your case, you say you are using an SSO system, so the 'default' login page would be whatever the login page of that system is.

Comment: If we *want* the username/password login prompt, browser settings can control whether or not the Windows authenticated user is automatically logged in (e.g. you might have IE set to "Automatic logon only in Intranet zone").

Answer (score 5):

Here is the link to the SSO configuration documentation ([login required](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)): http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_59979CAA10334D61979C34C85FA7703A

There are instructions on how to configure CA SiteMinder and Tivoli Access Manager, however, the configuration is not restricted to just these products.

Regarding a custom login page, I'm assuming you mean a page with a login form. Since the Tridion CME is built for SSO, there is no login page.  If you configure Tridion to sit behind a portal or SiteMinder, then you can use those products' functionality to host a login page.